# Could not decode JSON - Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead

Tags: json, swift, struct, decoder

I want to fetch some JSON data. I have made a Struct, but this Struct doesn't seem to work. When I run my code I will get this error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "match", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "time", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I am a newbie with JSON and Struct, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have searched on the Internet for similar problems but their solutions doesn't seem to work for me. 
Struct:

```
struct Data: Codable {
    var data: Match

    init(data: Match) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
struct Match: Codable {
    var match: [Live_Match]

    init(match: [Live_Match]) {
        self.match = match
    }
}

struct Live_Match: Codable {
    let competition_id: Int?
    let status: String?
    let ht_score: String?
    let ft_score: String?
    let et_score: String?
    let league_name: String?
    let away_id: Int?
    let score: String?
    let competition_name: String?
    let home_id: Int?
    let away_name: String?
    let time: Int?
    let home_name: String?
    let league_id: Int?

    init(competition_id: Int?, status: String?, ht_score: String?, ft_score: String?, et_score: String?, league_name: String?, away_id: Int?, score: String?, competition_name: String?, home_id: Int?, away_name: String?, time: Int?, home_name: String?, league_id: Int?) {
        self.competition_id = competition_id
        self.status = status
        self.ht_score = ht_score
        self.ft_score = ft_score
        self.et_score = et_score
        self.league_name = league_name
        self.away_id = away_id
        self.score = score
        self.competition_name = competition_name
        self.home_id = home_id
        self.away_name = away_name
        self.time = time
        self.home_name = home_name
        self.league_id = league_id
    }
}
```

Fetch function:

```
final let url_live = URL(string:"http://livescore-api.com/api-client/scores/live.json?key=6iNDEUYbh6NZHBdG&secret=RxkjBBp4h7MoKw2ROQvtLtE3zs2h4fXV&country=2")
    private var Live_Matches = [Live_Match]()

func downloadJson() {
        guard let downloadURL = url_live else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("downloaded")
            do
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedLive_Matches = try decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data)
                print(downloadedLive_Matches)
                self.Live_Matches = downloadedLive_Matches.data.match
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

JSON:

```
{
   "success": true,
   "data": {
      "match": [
         {
          "competition_id": 68,
          "status": "HALF TIME BREAK",
          "ht_score": "0 - 0",
          "ft_score": "",
          "et_score": "",
          "last_changed": "2019-07-28 16:52:14",
          "id": 151050,
          "league_name": "First Division A",
          "away_id": 806,
          "score": "0 - 0",
          "competition_name": "First Division A",
          "events": false,
          "home_id": 354,
          "away_name": "Gent",
          "added": "2019-07-28 15:45:20",
          "time": "HT",
          "home_name": "Sporting Charleroi",
          "league_id": 48
        }, //And some more data
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `print(error.localizedDescription)` in the `catch` block `print(error)`. The *real* error tells you exactly what's wrong and even where. And don't name your struct `Data`. There is a struct with the same name in the Foundation Framework.

Comment: when printing the error do `if let error = error { print(error)}` to get a more detailed error message

Comment: Thank you, It was a stupid mistake. The JSON data was a String instead of a Int.

Answer (score 1):

The coding path in the error message is telling you where the issue is (in `data`, in `match`, in the first array entry, and under the key `time`). Once you follow that coding path to the appropriate place in the JSON, you can see the `typeMismatch` issue, namely that you defined `time` to be `Int?`, but your JSON has a string, `"HT"`.